# Design pattern to enrich a class with new features

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, decorator

I have implemented a series of classes to manage search / detail page with *JSF* and *PrimeFaces*.
More in detail, I've created an abstract class `SearchDetailView<C extends BaseView, M>` in order to centralize common functionality for *Search/Detail* page.

In short, I've a class `MyView` that extends the base `SearchDetailView`.
Now I'd like to add another behavior to `MyView`, that is *Confirm Dialog*.

I'm wondering **what design pattern I have to use?** I was going to use the design pattern **Decorator**, but I don't need to add new behaviors at runtime, but I've already know what behaviors `MyView` needs.

I can't extends two classes (obviously), but I didn't like to have many combinations of "base" classes. I'd like to create a second abstract class like `ConfirmDialogDecorator` in order to add "programmatically" the extra functionality.

So, I ask you which design pattern add behavior to a class?

Actually my code is like the following:

```
public abstract class SearchDetailView<C extends BaseController, M> extends BaseView {
    [...]
}

public abstract class ConfirmDialogDecorator<C extends BaseController, M> extends SearchDetailView<C, M> { 

    public void showDialog(final String message) { [...] }

}

public class MyView extends ConfirmDialogDecorator<MyController, MyModel> { 
    [...]
}
```

But I'd like to separate `ConfirmDialogDecorator` from `SearchDetailView`.
Any idea? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
As suggested in the two answers I used the Java 8 default methods (*Mixin pattern*?):

```
public interface ConfirmDialog {

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog();

    default public String getConfirmMessage() {
        return "Do you confirm?";
    }

    default String getWidgetVar() {
        return "confirmDialog";
    }

    public void onConfirm();

    default void showDialog(final String message) {
        dialog.setWidgetVar(this.getWidgetVar());
        dialog.setMessage(message);
        dialog.showDialog(message);
    }

    class Dialog {

        private String message;
        private String widgetVar;

        String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        void setMessage(final String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public String getWidgetVar() {
            return widgetVar;
        }

        public void setWidgetVar(final String widgetVar) {
            this.widgetVar = widgetVar;
        }

        void showDialog(final String message) {
            final PrimeFaces current = PrimeFaces.current();
            current.executeScript("PF('" + this.widgetVar + "').show();");
        }
    }
}

public class MyView extends SearchDetailView<MyController, MyModel>
    implements ConfirmDialog {

    public void onSave() {
       if(!this.someCheck()) {
          this.showDialog("Are you really sure?");
       } else {
          this.save();
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfirm() {
        this.save();
    }

    public void save() {
       // The save
    }

}
```

In the xhtml:

```
<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="confirmDialog" global="true">
    <h:outputText value="#{myView.confirmMessage}" />
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="pi pi-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="pi pi-times" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Comment: I didn't understand the part when you said that Decorator pattern doesn't fit ? can you please explain ?

Comment: According to the pattern decorator, the class `Decorator` receives the super class as parameter in constructor and wraps some method adding "hidden" functions overriding the same method, isn't? I don't want to override some functionallity of `SearchDetailView` but add `ConfirmDialog` to `MyView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was going to use the design pattern Decorator, but I don't need to
>   add new behaviors at runtime, but I've already know what behaviors
>   MyView needs.

and then

> I'd like to create a second abstract class like ConfirmDialogDecorator
>   in order to add "dynamically" the extra functionality.

Don't you say a thing and its contrary ?
The fact that you know decorating possibilities at compile time doesn't mean that the pattern is not adapted.

> But I'd like to separate ConfirmDialogDecorator from SearchDetailView.

Decorator is also a alternative to subclassing and avoid classes hierarchies.
Using the pattern by introducing a decorator interface is probably a right way for your requirement.

As alternative Java 8 introduced the notion of default methods in interfaces that allows to add behaviors to classes implementing it.
In a some way, we can consider it as a way to decorate **statically** classes with additional behaviors without subclassing.  Note that as interfaces cannot define instance fields, default methods cannot use it either.  So you should consider this alternative according to this constraint.

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected the question, not "dinamically" but "programmatically".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried the "Java 8" solution (I've updated my question) and it worked, but I'd like to understand how could I use Decorator. According to the pattern decorator, the class Decorator receives the super class as parameter in constructor and wraps some method adding "hidden" functions overriding the same method, isn't? I don't want to override some functionallity of SearchDetailView but add ConfirmDialog to MyView. Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: @Alessandro.That is clearer with the edit. Thanks. Indeed, decorator enriches the decorated object behavior but it doesn't mean that you will override any feature of the decorated object. According to the requirement, it can also be considered as an addition. Before giving a example, I would like to be sure to understand your actual requirement and above all how you want to use the `showDialog()` method you introduced in the edited code.

Comment: You can see the almost complete code and use of `showDialog()` in my updated question. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. That is more clear now. Actually you don't want to use the decorator pattern because `ConfirmDialog` doesn't enrich the behavior of `MyView.`  I say it because here the logic of `MyView` requires both a check and a dialog. You use `ConfirmDialog` as a dependency/helper in `MyView`. You could use a decorator if `MyView` didn't make checks and that `ViewCheckDecorator` would make both the check and the dialog display.  I hope that I was clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Usually to add functionality to a class without inheritance be used [mixim/trait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) conception.

You can use [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) or aspect-objected programming in Java to the implementation of this conception

Comment: I don't know if mixin is a design pattern, certainly it's not in Gang of Four's list, but I like this answer and I think it's the most praticable... thank you.

Comment: @Alessandro You're right. It's not GoF pattern, it's conception for replacement of multiple inheritance :)

Comment: Well, GoF or not... anyway it worked, thank you.